# jQuery - div:contains not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to have jquery automatically fill an input if there is a specific phrase in a div

Here is what I have so far....

```
<li>
    <div>
        <div class="gfield_admin_header_title">Orange</div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="text" id="field_css_class" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div>
        <div class="gfield_admin_header_title">Apple</div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="text" id="field_css_class" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div>
        <div class="gfield_admin_header_title">Pear</div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="text" id="field_css_class" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>

$("div > div:contains('Orange')").find("#field_css_class").val('DesiredVal');
```

This isn't working for me, if I use...

```
$("div").find("#field_css_class").val('DesiredVal');
```

Then it does change the input but does it for all instances of #field_css_class (as expected)

So i am assuming its my div:contains that it doesn't like, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

First id must be unique so use `field_css_class` as a class attribute instead of using it as an id then

```
$("div").has('> div:contains("Orange")').find(".field_css_class").val('DesiredVal');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GzfW3/)

The problem is the element `field_css_class` is not an descendant of the div containing the text `Orange`, it is a descendant of a sibling element

Note: In your markup there is an extra `</div>` at the end of each `li` element

Comment: I can't get this to work,  the fields are being dynamically generated by by the Gravity Forms plugin in the WordPress dashboard and they each have #field_css_class, i can't change them to class

Comment: in that case `.find("#field_css_class")` instead of `.find(".field_css_class")`

Comment: I have tried that, it doesn't work for me.  It just applies it to all #field_css_class - Not just the one in the 'Orange' div

Comment: @fightstarr20 did you check http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GzfW3/2/ it works.. then there is some other problem

Comment: Yep, must be something else at play.  I am going to have a further look now

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the class, because id is not advisable to be repeated and there you can take it directly

```
$(".className").val("value")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$.each($('.gfield_admin_header_title'), function () {
    if ($(this).text() == "Orange") {
        $(this).next().find('.field_css_class').val('DesiredVal');
    };
});
```

Some notes:

1) `id` should be unique, you should use class instead (in this case `.field_css_class`)

2) Your HTML markup seem wrong, you have redundant closing `</div>` tag before last `div` inside each `li`

3) Above code check whether the text inside your expected `div` is orange or not, if yes then change the next `input` value.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fqZVJ/)**